# when we create scope factory?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to seed some data to my sotre context from the app entry point.
My question is why should i create scope on main method (within program.cs).
Instead of consuming service directly ?
What is the rational behind this best practice ?

Create scope

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
              
                var serv = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<StoreContext>();
               // ..... do stuff
            }
            host.Run();
        }
```

Consume directly

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
            var serv = host.Services.GetRequiredService<StoreContext>();
            // do some code here 

            host.Run();
        }
```

Comment: How have you registered your services in the `IServiceCollection`? Why or why not have you used `AddScoped()` for the service you registered?

Comment: I think the difference might be of exception when there is no service of type StoreContext.

Comment: Can Inject the dependencies https://avasay.github.io/dotnet/core/csharp/2019/11/18/How-to-Seed-Database-in-ASPNET-Core.html

Answer (score 3):

If you've registered your context with a `Scoped` lifetime (which is the default) then you will get an exception if you try to retrieve it from the root `ServiceProvider`. You will need to create a `IServiceScope` first and then request the services from there. This ensures that any dependencies that are also scoped (for example services dependant on the current request in a web app) can be resolved correctly as well.

To be clear: If you request from the root, **there is no scope**. You need a `scope` to request a `scope`d service; without one an exception will be thrown.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#call-services-from-main) under the heading "Call services from Main":

> Create an `IServiceScope` with `IServiceScopeFactory.CreateScope` to resolve a scoped service within the app's scope. This approach is useful to access a scoped service at startup to run initialization  tasks

Retrieving "directly" is reserved for singletons. If you register your context with a lifetime of `Singleton` then retrieving it from the root service provider will work just fine.

```
// register
services.AddDbContext<StoreContext>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
// use
var context = host.Services.GetRequiredService<StoreContext>();
```

Note that for contexts in a web application this should be avoided. For a console application where there's no concurrent use of the context this approach is fine.

Comment: You are absolutely right , but still, i dont understand why its throw exception. is it because by default  taking service from the root its a singletone and the default registration for context using services.AddDbContextis is a scoped ?

Comment: Because if you take from the root, **there is no scope**. You need a scope to be able to request a scoped service

Comment: To add on to what @erb601 said, scopes are necessary for services that are "not always" available, or have dependencies that aren't always available. E.g, services that depend on the HttpContext, which is only available within a request. So the exception thrown is to safeguard against scoped services failing to be fully resolved outside a scope, otherwise a service would produce unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @gerryc.inc I think I covered that with "this ensures that dependencies that are also scoped can be resolved correctly"

Comment: @erb601 you're welcome. If this answers your question don't forget to tick the "accept" checkmark. If it doesn't, let me know what I can do to improve it.